# Actions on different branching criteria LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was wondering, is there an effective way to implement branching logic in a collection using LINQ, without iterating the collection more than once.

For example

```
    foreach (string file in Files){

      if (file== "file1"){
        \\do something
      }
      else if (file== "file2")
        \\do something
      }
      else if (file== "file3")
        \\do something
      }
    }
```

I have found a solution using lookups but only works for if-else cases

```
var group = Files.ToLookup(f => f=="file1");

var file1Group= group[true].ToList();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you've found a solution, and it works, so...what's your question?

Comment: "but only works for if-else cases"   Doesn't look like much of a limitation, considering the only use case in the question is an if-else.

Comment: I don't see how your "solution" (2nd code snippet) is better than your first, nor to I see how the 1st is failing at the task.

Comment: I am probably new to stack overflow and didnt phrase my self correctly. The snippet is just an example, i was wondering how can i perform action based on conditional logic in a collection (string collection is an example) using LINQ. The grouping approach seems to me suboptimal, as i loop the collection once to split it into groups and one to perform an action for each group

Comment: @DimitrisM That's not iterating the source sequence more than once.

Comment: @Servy that is definitely iterating the source collection more than once - to be exact, twice.

Comment: Not every problem is a nail. Sometimes a `foreach` is the best solution, though I would consider a `switch` instead of chaining `if` - `else if`. In particular, LINQ is for querying data, not processing the data. Are you gathering up something from each `do something` to return in a new collection? If so, perhaps a `Select` is appropriate, otherwise don't try to force LINQ.

Comment: @NetMage No, it's iterating the source sequence exactly once, and then iterating an intermediate collection once.  That's *radically* different.

Comment: How different that is really depends on the definition of `Files`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Basically you project a new anonymous type with extra properties that you want to filter by, order by, group by or whatever.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Files = new string[] { "file1", "file2" };

            var withMetaData = Files.Select(z =>
                new { file = z, IsFile1 = z == "file1", IsFile2 = z == "file2"});

            // You can now OrderBy or GroupBy or whatever you fancy here

            foreach (var fileWithMetaData in withMetaData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileWithMetaData);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have a large number of reoccurring actions, which are defined before the loop and have to be reusable (otherwise the if...else as you already have is probably preferable), I've got a tendency to put references to those actions in a dictionary (or other collection). For this particular example (files), that would only make sense if multiple folders are processed with the same filenames, or the 'file*x*' parts are obtained from a substring, but the concept can be applied to any reoccurring branching logic.

The example below uses lambdas, but any existing method with the same signature can be used

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string,Action>{
    {"file1", () => Console.WriteLine("abc")},
    {"file2", () => {var foo ="def"; Console.WriteLine(foo);}},
};

//example call, only to show usage
foreach(var file in new[]{"file1","file1","file2","file1"})
    actions[file](); //nb, for the example no check was added. For real use 'TryGetValue' can be used
```

Of course, this is assuming an action has to be performed on each file, otherwise a group by can be used.

Since an action is used for each file the example itself doesn't make much sense, since there is no specific action for the individual files. So in an effort to create a somewhat more sensible example:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string,Action<string>>{
    {"file1", f => Console.WriteLine("abc: {0}", f)},
    {"file2", f => {var foo ="def"; Console.WriteLine(foo);}},
};

foreach(var file in new[]{@"c:\temp\file1",@"c:\someotherfolder\file1",@"c:\temp\file2",@"c:\abc\file1"})
    actions[Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)](file); //nb, for the example no check was added. For real use 'TryGetValue' can be used
```

Comment: Thank you @Me.Name, i like this approach with actions inside a dictionary..

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work may be of use @DimitrisM